# converting a stream of numbers to audio

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to figure out how to convert a (near realtime) stream of numbers to audio. It seems the answer lies somewhere in creating a custom wave using the `createOscillator` function, but I can't figure out how to both add new data to the wave and to play it with no or little delay. My setup –

let's imagine a web sockets-based system that is sending new data to my web page. (For now, I am just using a simple `setInterval()` to simulate the streaming nature of data.) For now, let's just assume the data are a string of integers between `min` and `max`.

Help and pointers appreciated, por favor.

Comment: But what do these numbers represent? If the numbers are samples of sound volume then they are basically already PCM data.

Comment: they are not samples of sound volume. For now, they are just synthetic random integers I am generating. In actual implementation, they could be readings from a sensor, scaled to whatever range I want. For example, I could be "audiofying" readings from a seismometer or a fitbit or whatever. Kinda irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
mynode = audio_context.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE, num_channels, num_channels);
```

or more directly just populate a buffer with your PCM data points as per

```
var node = context.createBufferSource()
  , buffer = context.createBuffer(1, 4096, context.sampleRate)
  , data = buffer.getChannelData(0);

for (var i = 0; i < 4096; i++) { // you replace this with logic to feed your PCM data
 data[i] = Math.random();
}

node.buffer = buffer;
node.loop = true;
node.connect(context.destination);
node.start(0);
```

a tricky bit is to assure you pay homage to the Web Audio API event loop which must never get starved or get somehow ignored too long otherwise you will hear pops and other audible indications you have ignored its feed times ... I suggest a buffer size as above ... too large and you introduce a noticable time delay between when you feed it and when it gets rendered ... too short and you may have created too hot a loop between audio data production and its consumption ... as a learning exercise I wrote https://github.com/scottstensland/websockets-streaming-audio which streams audio from a nodejs server to the browser using websockets which then gets rendered into audio using Web Audio API ... it may give you some tips

Looks like the current incantation is to use audioworker which is a callback executed when the Web Audio API event loop wants to get fed ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#Audio_Workers
 ... however until that gets fully baked into all browsers I suggest you still use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode ... pay particular attention to the callback onaudioprocess

Answer (score 0):

If the stream of integers is really the PCM data, you can convert them to float in some way (based on the `min` and `max` values).  Then create an `AudioBuffer` and copy your data to the `AudioBuffer` using `getChannelData()` or `copyToChannel()`.  This can be played out using an `AudioBufferSourceNode`.